# correct way of using fileTransfer() in phonegap for large number of images?

Tags: cordova

I am using phonegap's fileTransfer() API to upload some images to a remote server using post. When the number of images are less, everything works fine, by initiating upload for all the files without waiting for them to finish. But when i have say 200 images (approx 500Kb each), i am getting an out of memory error and anyways i want to avoid having so many uploads handled at the same time by apache. Is there a way to either upload images one after the other or restrict the number of simultaneous upload initiations it can do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not 100% sure that my idea would work, but technically it should. If you want to separate the number of files you send simultaniously, you can do the following: 
   I dont know if you calls are asynchronous, though they most likely are, but it doesnt really matter. 
   If you are not using they you should add the Q library to your project, or achieve the same thing using jQuery's promises. 
   First you wrap your call in a promise. Ofcourse, your call should have a function that recieves the data that it is sending.
   Something like this:

I am using the apache's documentation as an example

```
function uploadYourFiles(files) {
    var deffered = Q.Deffer();

    uploadFiles(files);

    function uploadFiles(files) {

        //the logic you use to upload you files
        //the win and error are the callback functions you get on the upload method
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);

        deffered.resolve(r);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);

        deffered.reject(error);
    }

    return deffered.promise;
}
```

Notice that the entire logic is wrapped in a promise.

Now that you have a promise of the whole operation, you can make this promise call itself with the next portion of your data, and in this way you would be sure that you are sending your files in pieces and be certain about the order of those pieces, because you will be sending the next N files when the first N files have already been send.

To hint how it should look in your code:

```
var from = 0;
var to = 10;
function uploadTheFiles() {
   var currentBatch = getFiles(from, to); //this function should return you the files from 0 to 10 for an instance

   uploadYourFiles(currentBatch).then(function () {
       from = to + 1;
       to += 10; //or however you want; You can insert some logic here to make sure to wont brake something by becoming bigger than your collection's length

       //this should serve as the end of the infinite recursion
       //files here is the array that contains your files. 
       //if you have their count or whatever, you can use it.
       if (from < files.length) {
           uploadTheFiles();
       }
   });
}
```

Hope that helps. If the only reason is that you don't have enough memory using promises you can make the uploading work piece by piece and at least by my logic this should not result in the not enough memory, as long as the interval you are sending is not too big of course.